# Aurigma PACKAGE UPLOAD ERROR - ERROR CODE 6

Tags: aurigma

We are testing the trail package on QA server and we encountered the following issue.please help us to fix this issue

we tried  uploading the folder of 2GB using HTML5 uploader, it is working in Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox v54 it is getting failed. we tried uploading 2Gb folder for 4 times but in all 4 times it failed. so we enabled the aurigma debug mode and then uploaded the 2GB folder it showed package uploader error.

> [htmluploader_trace] [WARNING] Package upload error 
>       { errorCode: 6, errorMessage: "Internal Server Error [500]", responseText: "" }

In apache error log it showed

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Upload
>   request is invalid.' in
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/ImageUploaderFlashPHP/UploadSession.class.php:142\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/ImageUploaderFlashPHP/UploadSession.class.php(32):
>   UploadSession->validateRequest()\n#1
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/ImageUploaderFlashPHP/UploadHandler.class.php(135):
>   UploadSession->processRequest()\n#2
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/ImageUploaderFlashPHP/UploadHandler.class.php(186):
>   UploadHandler->processRequest()\n#3
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/Aurigmabackend.php(10):
>   UploadHandler->saveFiles('/mnt/uploads/di...')\n#4 
>   /home/application/controllers/create.php(565):
>   Aurigmabackend->initialize('/uploads/di...')\n#5 [internal function]:
>   create->htmlflashupload()\n#6 /home/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#7 /home/index.php(203):
>   require_once('/home/...')\n#8 in
>   /home/application/libraries/aurigma/ImageUploaderFlashPHP/UploadSession.class.php
>   on line 142.

We further investigated the error in html5 uploader in Firefox. we added the log in the backend and checked the post parameters that are been sent from client. we found that some of the post parameters were missing for a file that failed to upload.

Missing post parameters were RequestCount, PackageComplete and RequestComplete but these parameters are their in the post parameters in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

- Error code 6 is - goog.net.ErrorCode.HTTP_ERROR, The Http response
  returned a non-successful http status code (500)
- Https status 500 -
  is a server error.
- Upload request is invalid - Aurigma Uploader
  request consists of some required fields such as
  packageGuid,requestComplete,packageCount.

Your request is
   incomplete and don't have all required fields. Check constructor of UploadSession.php. Check $_POST and $post objects

If you can't find error yourself, you may ask a help from Aurigma support team.